# Video player still playing after closing modal

Tags: javascript, video, model

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;">&times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                   <video id='videoPlayer' width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls">
                        <source id='mp4Source' src="" type="video/mp4" />
                        <!--<source id='oggSource' src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />-->
                     </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function play(i){  


    var x = document.getElementById("hidden_"+i).value;

    var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');

    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');

    player.pause();

      // Now simply set the 'src' property of the mp4Vid variable!!!!

    mp4Vid.src = x;


    player.load();
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
}
```

I play a video inside the modal but when I click out side of the modal before the video completes the modal will hide but the the video continues to play

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `hide.bs.modal`. Check the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    player.pause();
})
```

Comment: play(i) means what??

Comment: Consider approving and up voting my answer if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
         player.pause();
})
```

Comment: please add an explanation as to how this solves the issue - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15479771)